# Gstreamer Video Overlay Invalid Cast on QWidget , Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt, gstreamer

Problem is I couldn't stream camera or any video in QWidget. I can do it without Qt but I need to do in QWidget. The syntax is fine. QWidget appears but nothing in it. I used GstElement* for source and sink.

data.source = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosrc", "source");
data.sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");

In Command Line it works fine when I write 
" gst-launch-1.0 autovideosrc ! autovideosink "

However, it doesn't work on code.

QApplication::sync();
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(GST_ELEMENT(data.sink)),guintptr(ui.widget->winId()));

It gives this error:

GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GstAutoVideoSink' to 'GstVideoOverlay'

** (QtGuiApplication2.exe:6188): CRITICAL **: gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle: assertion 'GST_IS_VIDEO_OVERLAY (overlay)' failed

<<< This problem is at almost everywhere but still there is no clear solution both in stackoverflow, qtcentre and gstreamer developer forum. I know someone would have solved this already but please reply to forums...>>> 

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`autovideosink` does not expose the `GstVideoOverlay` interface. Because it is not a real renderer but merely an auto-plug helper. Sometime after you start the pipeline it decides to plug in an actual renderer.

You should add a bus sync handler to check for the prepare overlay message and then do the video overlay calls. The documentation shows the basic idea with examples:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/GstVideoOverlay.html

Comment: As I searched in web deeply, autovideosink provides auto window not that I specified. Some people suggested appsink and glimagesink. I used them but "appsink" gives the same error, invalid cast and it gives no window. "glimagesink" gave no error but did not display anything as well. By the way, the link you provided, I've looked into it. It did not work either.

Comment: appsink does not provide a video overlay interface either. So the error is kind of expected.

Comment: People who might have the same problem, try to use glimagesink it exposes GstVideoOverlay. As Florian Zwoch said, sinks which does not expose GstVideoOverlay won't work. Try to use gst-inspect-1.0 | grep "sink" , to see various sinks. After you implemented glimagesink, you cannot display QWidget because threads come into it. You should make a thread mechanism for your program in order to display QWidget and also doing other things.

Comment: give `xvimagesink` a try.